# Can we manage incoming call number landing on asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I am using Asterisk 1.4.2 in two different machine. I have configured some extensions in asterisk. When any caller, dial my extension number with local number then if I see asterisk console (asterisk -r) then incoming number is starting with 0, but if caller dial same extension number using STD number then in asterisk console (asterisk -r), incoming number is staring with 0091 (here 91 is country code).

Could I change this setting or is there any standard for asterisk for local, STD or ISD number?

Answer (score 1):

There's no single standard.  You've got two choices: either add a dialplan entry to modify the presented incoming number for one of the two cases (ie, for calls matching 0091), or make sure that both types of calls go through a single dialplan/flow that defines a common source number format.

In either case, your dialplan needs to rewrite some or all source numbers.

Given that, choose a format that will last.  At Cloudvox, we went with E.164 (+CCnumber)  because it fairly cleanly supports worldwide numbers.  We rewrite caller ID values to E.164 and present that CID to apps. http://help.cloudvox.com/faqs/getting-started/incoming-call-settings is one version of what I described above.

Troy, Cloudvox